# Optional call-by-name parameter without parentheses

Tags: scala

I would like a method with 2 call-by-name parameters, where one is optional, but still call it without parentheses. So you can do either:

```
transaction { ... }
```

or

```
transaction { ... } { ... }
```

I tried (and settled for):

```
def transaction(body: => Unit) { transaction(body, {}) }
def transaction(body: => Unit, err: => Unit) { ... } // Works by transaction({ ... },{ ... })
```

Which apparently is different from (for a reason I don't know):

```
def transaction(body: => Unit, err: => Unit = {}) { ... }
```

And the one I hoped would work (but I guess doesn't because the first parameter list is the same).

```
def transaction(body: => Unit) { transaction(body)() }
def transaction(body: => Unit)(err: => Unit) { ... }
```

How would you use the concept of a optional second call-by-name parameter?

Comment: When you say "apparently different from", what do you mean? In what case doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how default parameter works. Notice:

```
scala> def f(x:Int = 5) = println(x)
f: (x: Int)Unit

scala> f
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method f in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              f
              ^

scala> f()
5
```

Methods with default parameters always requires the () to be invoked.

So, to make the case with two parameters lists and a default parameter work we need:

```
scala> def transaction(body: => Unit)(err: => Unit = { println("defult err")}) { body; err; }
transaction: (body: => Unit)(err: => Unit)Unit

scala> transaction { println("body") } 
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method transaction in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              transaction { println("body") } 

scala> transaction { println("body") } ()
body
defult err
```